# Not reporting true when I think it should, instead reporting all false

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/QhL2M/
(type "bye" into the input box")

Purpose of the script: Each `li` contains tag words in it. When the user types one of these tag words in the `input` box, it will hide all of the `li`'s that do not contain that tag word. Multiple words may be typed into the `input`, if more than 1 `li`'s tag words matches any of the words in the `input`, then they are shown. So it's basically a filtered list that allows for multiple words, and shows all matching `li`'s that contain any of the words typed into the `input`. It only matches whole words, not partial words, and it should only update the list of matches when another whole word has been matched(when multiple words). This is the goal.

My problem is that it's incorrectly reporting that there's a match in this piece of code:

```
 if (matches == true) {
    alert('matched true')  //incorrectly reports  
 } else {
    alert('matched false') //incorrectly reports  
 }
```

while this piece of code is reporting correctly:

```
if (regex.test($(this).text()) === true) {
    matches = true;
    // alert('tis true') //correctly reports  
} else {
       matches = false;
       // alert('tis false') //correctly reports   
}
```

Why is it not reporting correctly? (correctly, as in: what I want it to report)

If anyone is good enough at Javascript to see what i'm trying to do and knows how to help me, that'd be fantastic. I'm trying to work my way through this because there's just a few things left to change.

Comment: Is matches a global variable? Could be overwritten. Have you tried putting debugger statements after the regex and inspect the value of matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are looping through all of the list items with:

```
$("#list li").each(function() {
```

and then within each iteration you loop through the list of words with:

```
$.each(inputWords, function(i, a_filter) {
```

and then in the *inner* loop you again process *all* li elements with:

```
var containing = $('#list li').filter(function () {
```

So then in the inner part you're getting confused about just what you're dealing with. I think what you need to do is loop through each element, testing if it has any matches to the input word list, and then hide or show that element as appropriate. Something like this:

```
var inputWords = inputValue.toLowerCase().split(/[\s,]+/);

$("#list li").each(function() {
    var matches = false,
        $currentElement = $(this);

    $.each(inputWords, function(i, a_filter) {
        if ($.trim(a_filter)==="") return; // skip blank items

        var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + a_filter + ')(s|es|\'s)?\\b', 'i');
        if (regex.test($currentElement.text())) {
            matches = true;
            return false;  // return false breaks out of the $.each
                           // (no need to continue once a match is found)
        }
     });

     if (matches)
        $currentElement.slideDown(400);
     else
        $currentElement.slideUp();
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QhL2M/19/

EDIT: also the way you were splitting the input word list didn't work for me:

```
var inputWords = $('.filterinput').text().toLowerCase().split(/[\s,]+/);
// I've changed that to
var inputWords = inputValue.toLowerCase().split(/[\s,]+/);
```

You don't want to use `.text()` on an input, and in any case `inputValue` was already initialised earlier to hold the text of that input. My code above and demo have been updated.

Comment: oh man you're awesome. You actually understood me and knew exactly what to do, it's beautiful. One thing i noticed that i can't figure out though: is that after the first word i hit space, or comma, and it will show the entire list again. I can't get it to continue only showing the li's with matches. So the user only sees the list animate/show/hide when either a new li is matched, or the user deletes a word/letter of a word(causing that word to no longer match), does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly (including the link to an updated fiddle). The problem was when you split the input when space or comma was the last item (or if you entered several spaces or commas in a row) you ended up with empty strings in the inputWords array, so the regex formed around those empty strings matched every list item. So I added a line `if ($.trim(a_filter)==="") return;` to skip to the next iteration of `$.each` when the current item is blank.

Comment: Oh, and while I was at it I changed the regex declaration to be case insensitive because otherwise (given you were changing the search string to lowercase) it wouldn't ever match on uppercase words. Try out my updated fiddle.

Comment: 1) Wow THANK-YOU. Nearly perfect. If you could help me out with these final 2 small bugs, I would be really appreciative, if you don't have time, I understand - you've helped me out so much. If you start typing in the input box, and have more than 2 character but don't yet have a match, it hides all of the LI's. Is there a way to keep all of the LI's visible until you have a match, THEN slideUp/slideDown what needs to be hidden/shown? - so the user doesn't start typing and then all the LI's disappear when there's not yet even a match?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you try to accomplish ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/QhL2M/15/)):

```
(function($) {
    function fiKeyup() {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        if (inputValue.length > 2) {
            var inputWords = inputValue.split(/[\s,]+/ig);
            var containing = $('#list li').filter(function () {
                var ret = false;
                var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                $.each(inputWords, function(i, a_filter) {
                    var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + a_filter + ')(s|es|\'s)?\\b');
                    if(regex.test(text)) {
                        return !(ret = true);
                    }
                });
                return ret;
            });

            $('#list li').not(containing).slideUp();
        } else {
            $('#list li').slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    };
    var timeout;

    $('.filterInput').keyup(function() {
        var that = this;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            fiKeyup.call(that);
        }, 500);
    });

}(jQuery));
```